# Create points from lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, geometry-conversion

I used the Bearing Distance to Line command (Data Management) in arc to convert UTM coords (i.e. of a plot center), bearing and distance to the figure shown below.  The end of each line represents a tree location.  How can I convert these lines to points in order to represent tree locations as a point shapefile?  Thanks for the help.
[image]

**Edit**:  The final model and final product based on help from others:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the feature to vertices tool in Arcgis

Answer (score 1):

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12666

You can use the following script to get geometries of each vertices for shapefiles. (not just lines)

Enjoy.

My Bad, easier way is to add two new double fields to your attributes. Then you can calculate coordinates of start, mid and end point of your lines (whichever you are interested). Exporting these coordinates you will have set of points (e.g. in a text file) that you may use to create a point shapefile to visualize your trees.